# Multiple arguments in bottle's route

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

In bottle, the route like this:

```
@get('/ws/contacts/:uid')
```

how can i add more arguments to the route, and how to code the @get() ?

Comment: An example with routing: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use multiple wildcards:

```
@get('/ws/contacts/:uid/:itemid')
def get_user_item(uid, itemid):
    return 'you passed in uid={} and itemid={}'.format(uid, itemid)
```

---

P.S., You're using a deprecated wildcard syntax.  Unless you're required to use an old version of Bottle (0.9 or earlier), I recommend that you use the [modern syntax](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#rule-syntax), like this:

```
@get('/ws/contacts/<uid:int>/<itemid:int>')
```